# Tramp connection history mysteriously appearing in .emacs.d

Tags: tramp

Today when reviewing changes to my .emacs.d before committing, I noticed a file called `tramp`. The contents of this file are as follows:

```
;; -*- emacs-lisp -*- <16/12/28 15:56:06 /home/ethan/.emacs.d/tramp>
;; Tramp connection history.  Don't change this file.
;; You can delete it, forcing Tramp to reapply the checks.

((["scp" nil "fcp" nil nil]
  nil))
```

I am curious how/why this file was created. I can see from [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Connection-caching) what this file does, and how to disable the creation of the file, but I am wondering why it has suddenly appeared since I have never used `tramp`, and have never seen this file generated before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading `tramp-cache` causes this to happen:

```
(unless noninteractive
  (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook 'tramp-dump-connection-properties))
```

(which writes that file when emacs exits.)

Undoubtedly `tramp-cache` *was* loaded, either unwittingly by yourself, or by some other library that you use.

That particular library is loaded automatically by other tramp functionality, so most likely something else triggered it indirectly.

Even if you don't mean to use the functionality, it's not particularly difficult to trigger tramp by accidentally typing a filename with a tramp handler. Emacs won't know it was a typo, after all.

(Or maybe you only *think* you don't use tramp? Perhaps you've used `/sudo::/path/to/file` to edit a system file, for instance?)